# How to retrieve content-disposition value in React JS?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have one download API in that if i can excute in header getting value i need that value by react js code.

[image]

In above API run in postman header that value getting of content-disposition i need to fetch file name from that i have try in react js but not getting variable of content-disposition.

```
Method 1 :- 

const response = await fetch('https://localhost/api/v2/fax/download/10019400/9cb9c99f-0d57-         46b9-925a-8df05afa1d75');
console.log(response);

Method 2 :-

export const DownloadFile = (res: any, name: string) => {
const filename = getFilenameFromContentDisposition(res);
const blob = new Blob([res], { type: "application/pdf" });
const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
const a = document.createElement("a");

a.href = url;
//a.download = `${name}.pdf`;
a.download = filename;
a.style.display = "none";
document.body.appendChild(a);
a.click();
document.body.removeChild(a);
};
const getFilenameFromContentDisposition = (response: Response) => {
const contentDisposition = response.headers.get("Content-Disposition");
if (contentDisposition) {
  const matches = /filename=([^;]+)/g.exec(contentDisposition);
  if (matches) {
    const filename = matches[1].trim();
    return filename;
  }
}
// If the header is not present or doesn't contain a filename, use a default name
return "downloaded-file.pdf";
};
```

Answer (score 0):

in the postman you can get the code :
go to code, choose javascript fetch, and copy this code.
[image]

Comment: var myHeaders = new Headers();
myHeaders.append("Authorization", "Bearer token");
var requestOptions = {
  method: 'GET',
  headers: myHeaders,
  redirect: 'follow'
};
fetch("downloadurl", requestOptions)
  .then(response => {
    if (response.headers.has("content-disposition")) {
      var contentDisposition = response.headers.get("content-disposition");
      console.log(contentDisposition);
    } else {
      console.log("Content-Disposition Header Not Found");
    }
    return response.text();
  })
  .then(result => console.log(result)); 

Res

Content Header Not Found